# Retrieve Node-Red flows

Tags: node-red

I had my Node-Red running as windows service with the help of daemon tool. Unfortunately it stopped working. Not sure why. I have created some flows which I wish to retrieve from the node-red so that, I can re-install node-red again from scratch and use the flows that i have created already. Could anyone help me where the flows are actually stored and the configurations, packages installed details?
Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: In my case the flows are stored in `c:\SPB_Data\.node-red`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flows will be stored in the `.node-red` in the profile directory of the user running node-red.

The default directory is `c:\Users\[username]\.node-red`

The flow will be made up of 2 files:

- `flows_[hostname].json`
- `flows_[hostname]_creds.json`

The first is the actual flow, the second is where any username/passwords used by the flow is kept. This second file is normally encrypted with a key generated the first time node-red is run. The key is stored in the `.config.json` in the same directory.

Comment: Do you also know how to do in Raspbian (Debian-based Linux)?